# Logic of transfer function (ft) for a MOSFET in gm over id

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to learn the gm over id of a MOSFET from [this manual]([https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~boser/presentations/2011-12](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eboser/presentations/2011-12) OTA gm Id.pdf) as shown below.

Where did the formula below come from?

Is there some theoretical background I could use? I am using the spice model shown below. What is the proper spice parameter for the Cgs capacitance?

[image]

```
.MODEL CMOSNN NMOS (                                LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 4.1E-9
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 2.3549E17      VTH0    = 0.3662473
+K1      = 0.5864999      K2      = 1.127266E-3    K3      = 1E-3
+K3B     = 0.0294061      W0      = 1E-7           NLX     = 1.630684E-7
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 1.2064649      DVT1    = 0.4215486      DVT2    = 0.0197749
+U0      = 273.8094484    UA      = -1.40499E-9    UB      = 2.408323E-18
+UC      = 6.504826E-11   VSAT    = 1.355009E5     A0      = 2
+AGS     = 0.4449958      B0      = 1.901075E-7    B1      = 4.99995E-6
+KETA    = -0.0164863     A1      = 3.868769E-4    A2      = 0.4640272
+RDSW    = 123.3376355    PRWG    = 0.5            PRWB    = -0.197728
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 0              LINT    = 1.690044E-8
+XL      = 0              XW      = -1E-8          DWG     = -4.728719E-9
+DWB     = -2.452411E-9   VOFF    = -0.0948017     NFACTOR = 2.1860065
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 2.230928E-3    ETAB    = 6.028975E-5
+DSUB    = 0.0145467      PCLM    = 1.3822069      PDIBLC1 = 0.1762787
+PDIBLC2 = 1.66653E-3     PDIBLCB = -0.1           DROUT   = 0.7694691
+PSCBE1  = 8.91287E9      PSCBE2  = 7.349607E-9    PVAG    = 1.685917E-3
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 6.7            MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 0              UTE     = -1.5           KT1     = -0.11
+KT1L    = 0              KT2     = 0.022          UA1     = 4.31E-9
+UB1     = -7.61E-18      UC1     = -5.6E-11       AT      = 3.3E4
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 8.23E-10       CGSO    = 8.23E-10       CGBO    = 1E-12
+CJ      = 9.466429E-4    PB      = 0.8            MJ      = 0.3820266
+CJSW    = 2.608154E-10   PBSW    = 0.8            MJSW    = 0.102322
+CJSWG   = 3.3E-10        PBSWG   = 0.8            MJSWG   = 0.102322
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = -2.199373E-3   PRDSW   = -0.9368961
+PK2     = 1.593254E-3    WKETA   = -2.880976E-3   LKETA   = 7.165078E-3
+PU0     = 6.777519       PUA     = 5.505418E-12   PUB     = 8.84133E-25
+PVSAT   = 2.006286E3     PETA0   = 1.003159E-4    PKETA   = -6.759277E-3
+NOIMOD=2.0E+00                 NOIA=1.3182567385564E+19
+NOIB=144543.977074592 NOIC=-1.24515784572817E-12               EF=0.92 EM=41000000 )
```

Comment: Check out `CGS0` and `CGD0` definitions in the BSIM3v3.3 manual:  https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/external-documents/models/bsim330_manual.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transit frequency ft is the frequency at wich the small signal current gain with a 0 Ohm load is equal to 1. This is generally a high frequency depending on the device and is a measure of its speed. The higher this frequency is, the faster the device is considered to be.

Based on the small signal circuit with a schort circuit load the current gain can be calculated from the small signal model, and found to be  :
[image]

From this, you can approximate and simplify the transit frequency, with the gain set to unity, at very high frequencies to be the equation you quoted, noting that at high frequencies :  [image]